# How to replace a component used in @viewChildren for a test double?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-testing

Suppose I have a component I want to test that uses a very complex component. Furthermore it calls some of its methods using references obtained by `@viewChildren`. For example

```
    @Component({
        moduleId: module.id,
        selector: 'test',
        template: '<complex *ngFor='let v of vals'></complex>' ,
    })
    export class TestComponent{
    vals = [1,2,3,4]
    @ViewChildren(ComplexComponent) cpxs : QueryList<ComplexComponent>
    // ....
    }
```

How can I replace the complex-component for a test double in `TestBed'?

Something like

```
@Component({
  moduleId : module.id,
  selector: 'complex', template: ''
})
class ComplexComponentStub {
}

describe('TestComponent', () => {
  beforeEach( async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations : [ComplexComponentStub, TestComponent],
    });
it('should have four sons',()=>{
   let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
   let comp    = fixture.componentInstance as TestComponent;
   fixture.detectChanges();
   expect(comp.cpxs.length).toBe(4);
});

    //....
}));
```

For a full example see the plnkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/ybdrN8VimzktiDCTvhwe?p=preview

Comment: I'm not sure that it's the right way but you can check out this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/1w04DDKnYQ7kH6tIE0pK?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works

Comment: However the `cpxs` appears to be empty on my tests... The doubles are effectively created, but the list `@ViewChildren`selector will not match, and therefore the functions inside the test component that use `cpxs`can't be tested

Comment: Can you add plunker that reproduces it?

Comment: I just added the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ybdrN8VimzktiDCTvhwe?p=preview)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/cr8ErnDzpQg8LI4XdCnE?p=preview

Comment: This works, thanks a lot. You should add it as an answer. Do you know where can I find documentation about Reflect and the propMetaData object you are retrieving?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65956284/98422) for a discussion of how to resolve this issue on Angular 10+.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reflect-metadata features to do it working:

```
it('should have four sons', () => {
   const propMetadata = Reflect['getMetadata']('propMetadata', FatherComponent);
   var originType = propMetadata.cpxs[0].selector;
   propMetadata.cpxs[0].selector = ComplexComponentStub; // Replace ViewChild Type

   let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FatherComponent);

   let comp = fixture.componentInstance as FatherComponent;
   fixture.detectChanges();
   expect(comp.cpxs.length).toBe(4);

   propMetadata.cpxs[0].selector = originType; // reset ViewChild
});
```

**[Test in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cr8ErnDzpQg8LI4XdCnE?p=preview)**

You can read more about decorators and about reflect-metadata here:

- [Angular 2, decorators and class inheritance](https://medium.com/@ttemplier/angular2-decorators-and-class-inheritance-905921dbd1b7#.efvdur127)

Comment: Note that in Angular 5 this solution seems to no longer work. However I've found that `(MyComponent as any)['__prop__metadata__'].child[0].selector = ChildDirectiveMock;` should work but it doesn't feel like a very good permanent solution.

Comment: Thanks. (MyComponent as any)['__prop__metadata__'].child[0].selector = ChildDirectiveMock; is working

Answer (score 1):

if u just want to test the function in child component are called or not u can try this

component.ts

```
@ViewChildren('childComponent') childComponents: QueryList<YourComponent>;
```

component.spec.ts

```
  it('Your test name', () => {
    component.dashboard = dashboardMock; // ur using ngFor so u need to populate it first. u can mock it with ur own data
    fixture.detectChanges(); // component will render the ngfor
    const spies = [];
    component.childComponents.toArray().forEach((comp) => {
      comp.childFunction = () => { // Mock the function.
         return 'Child function called!';
      };
      const tempSpy = {
        spyKey: spyOn(comp, 'functionToBeMocked') // spy the mocked function
      };
      spies.push(tempSpy); // add to array
    });
    component.functionToTest(); // call the function u wish to test
    spies.forEach((spy) => { 
      expect(spy.spyKey).toHaveBeenCalled(); // check if child function are called
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65956284/98422) for a discussion of how to resolve this issue with Angular 10 (since none of the techniques described here work beyond Angular 9).

Answer (score 0):

Note that in Angular 5 this solution seems to no longer work. However joshhunt has found that (MyComponent as any)['**prop__metadata**'].child[0].selector = ChildDirectiveMock; should work but it doesn't feel like a very good permanent solution. – joshhunt

Comment: This worked up to Angular 9, but no longer works in Angular 10. :-(